# QT 2-dimensional array graphical grid

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, grid

I am making a 2-dimensional grid (2-d Cellular Automaton). So I made full code for console. But now I need to implement that with GUI. I am using linux, so I read out that QT Creator will be the best choice.
Can somebody give me a small tip. How is better to start. Which Views/widjets you recommend to use for that? Any help would be useful.
In c++ code I made a 2-dimensional char array of size 15/15 elements which have elements of type '1' or '0'.
I will be very grateful for any help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of ways: create a QImage and fill it with your data using `setPixel`. Convert it to QPixmap and use QLabel to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the two simple examples of how to show arrays on GUI. There are possible other variations too, of course, depending on your needs.

Widget with a grid layout

```
QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget;
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
for (int r = 0; r < 15; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 15; c++) {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel("1", mainWidget); // Text could be 1 or 0.
        layout->addWidget(label, r, c);
    }
}
mainWidget->setLayout(layout);
mainWidget->show();
```

Using table view

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(15, 15);
for (int r = 0; r < 15; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 15; c++) {
         QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem("1"); // Text could be 1 or 0.
         table->setItem(r, c, item);
    }
}
table->show();
```